# Mvc3 Wizard with separate controller actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm putting together a wizard in mvc3/c#. I have a model setup roughly

```
public interface IStepView {}

public class Step1View : IStepView {}

public class Step2View : IStepView {}
```

I have a parent view which displays 1 of 2 partial views for these steps.

I would like the form submission for Step 2 to use a custom action on the same controller. Reading similar posts it seems what I need to do is add a custom route like so

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Step2Route", "", new { controller = "Demo", action = "MyAction" });
```

which I wire together on the Main.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  
    @Html.BeginRouteForm("Step2Route", new { controller = "RolloverController", action = "Stuff" })

    // and so on for each Step I want to use a custom action


}
```

Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't know the number of steps in the wizard, a custom route might make sense to allow for tracking of progress in the wizard.

i.e. Wizard/{WizardName}Step/{StepNumber}/

But since it looks like you do know the steps, your actions on the controller can correspond to them without custom routes:

i.e RegistrationWizard/EnterInfo, RegistrationWizard/Confirm, RegistrationWizard/Success

Create a get and post method for each action on the controller. Take the same model and pass it along using RedirectToAction or store it in session, so that you keep track of the changes that the user is making to the data before committing the data on the final step.

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense than what I'm trying.